# String category names with Wisp scala plotting library

Tags: scala, charts, highcharts

I am trying to plot bars for String categories with [Wisp](https://github.com/quantifind/wisp). In other words, I have a string (key) and a count (value) in my repl and I want to have a bar chart of the count versus the key.

I don't know if something easy exists. I went as far as the following hack:

```
val plot = bar(topWords.map(_._2).toList)
val axisType: com.quantifind.charts.highcharts.AxisType.Type = "category"
val newPlot = plot.copy(xAxis = plot.xAxis.map {
  axisArray => axisArray.map { _.copy(axisType = Option(axisType),
                                      categories = Option(topWords.map(_._1))) }
})
```

but I don't know if it works because I don't find a way to visualize `newPlot`. Or maybe adding a method to the Wisp source implementing the above is the way to go?

Thanks for any help.

PS : I don't have the reputation to create the wisp tag, but I would have...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: in wisp 0.0.5 or later this will be supported directly:

```
column(List(("alpha", 1), ("omega", 5), ("zeta", 8)))
```

[image]

====

Thanks for trying out wisp (I am the author). I think a problem that you may have encountered is by naming your variable `plot`, you overrode access to the `plot` method defined by `Highcharts`, which allows you to plot any `Highchart` object. (now that I see it, naming your plot "plot" is an unfortunately natural thing to do!)

I'm filing this as a github issue, as category names are very common.

This works for me. I used `column` for vertical bars:

```
import com.quantifind.charts.Highcharts._
val topWords = Array(("alpha", 14), ("beta", 23), ("omega", 18))
val numberedColumns = column(topWords.map(_._2).toList)
val axisType: com.quantifind.charts.highcharts.AxisType.Type = "category"
val namedColumns = numberedColumns.copy(xAxis = numberedColumns.xAxis.map {
  axisArray => axisArray.map { _.copy(axisType = Option(axisType),
                                       categories = Option(topWords.map(_._1))) }
})
plot(namedColumns)
```

producing this visualization: [image]

(You could also consider creating one bar at a time, and use the legend to name them)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! Problem is that I don't have this behaviour. `numberedColumns` generate the first plot, but executing the `namedColumns` doesn't produce anything. Then again, I tried in the spark-shell (where I ultimately wants to use wisp). For the record, `namedColumns` returns `com.quantifind.charts.highcharts.Highchart = Highchart(List(Series(Vector(Data(0,14,None,None), Data(1,23,None,None), Data(2,18,None,None)),None,None,None,Some(column),None,None,None,None,series)),`... which looks wrong. I will test in a scala repl to see if your solution works there.

Comment: no luck with the sbt console, same behavior. PS I: tried on mac and linux for spark-shell, only on linux for sbt console. PS II: I pulled wisp and built a fat jar just now to do the test, but using scala 2.10.4, don't know if it matters.

Comment: Ah - I left it out of the response. You have to call `plot(namedColumns)`. I tested this in the spark shell and it worked for me. Do you see two plots or only one?

Comment: ouch. Sorry for the blind copy paste... thanks a lot! it works.

Comment: Hey, I've modified wisp to more directly support named axis categories. Checkout the PR: https://github.com/quantifind/wisp/pull/31 Should go out with wisp 0.0.5

Comment: I saw that! Thx a lot!