# Wisp, Scala, Spark

Tags: scala, charts, highcharts, apache-spark

Trying to do this: [String category names with Wisp scala plotting library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28887086/string-category-names-with-wisp-scala-plotting-library)

appDiagnostics: Application application_1422443857468_0507 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1422443857468_0507_000002 exited with  exitCode: -1000 due to: File does not exist: hdfs://service-10-0.local:8020/user/fredrikb/.sparkStaging/application_1422443857468_0507/spark-assembly-1.1.0.2.1.5.0-702-hadoop2.4.0.2.1.5.0-695.jar

This is the error i get. Seems like i am missing this: spark-assembly-1.1.0.2.1.5.0-702-hadoop2.4.0.2.1.5.0-695.jar

sbt code:

```
name := "PlotTest"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq( "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.1.0",
        "com.quantifind" %% "wisp" % "0.0.4"
)
```

scala code:

```
import com.quantifind.charts.Highcharts._

object HarryPlotter{
    def main(args: Array[String]){
      val topWords = Array(("alpha", 14), ("beta", 23), ("omega", 18))
      val numberedColumns = column(topWords.map(_._2).toList)
      val axisType: com.quantifind.charts.highcharts.AxisType.Type = "category"
      val namedColumns = numberedColumns.copy(xAxis = numberedColumns.xAxis.map {
      axisArray => axisArray.map { _.copy(axisType = Option(axisType),
                                   categories = Option(topWords.map(_._1))) }
      })
      plot(namedColumns)

      }
   }
```

I am new to this so i have no idea what the problem is!

Ultimately i want to make a bar chart of a List((int key, int value), (int key, int value)......) so im open to suggestions for other ways than Wisp to do that.

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/hdisk9/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/fredrikb/filecache/36/spark-assembly-1.1.0.2.1.5.0-702-hadoop2.4.0.2.1.5.0-695.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
15/04/24 17:20:50 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Registered signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
15/04/24 17:20:52 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: ApplicationAttemptId: appattempt_1422443857468_0511_000001
15/04/24 17:20:52 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at service-10-2.local/10.10.255.234:8030
15/04/24 17:20:52 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: yarn,fredrikb
15/04/24 17:20:52 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: yarn,fredrikb
15/04/24 17:20:52 INFO spark.SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(yarn, fredrikb); users with modify permissions: Set(yarn, fredrikb)
15/04/24 17:20:52 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Starting the user JAR in a separate Thread
15/04/24 17:20:52 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Waiting for Spark context initialization
15/04/24 17:20:52 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Waiting for Spark context initialization ... 0
15/04/24 17:20:52 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Unregistering ApplicationMaster with FAILED
Exception in thread "Driver" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:156)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/quantifind/charts/repl/IterablePair
    at HarryPlotter.main(HarryPlotter.scala)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.quantifind.charts.repl.IterablePair
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 6 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed
    at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.waitForSparkContextInitialized(ApplicationMaster.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$main$1.apply$mcV$sp(ApplicationMaster.scala:404)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$1.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$1.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:52)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1594)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil.runAsSparkUser(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:403)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.main(ApplicationMaster.scala)
15/04/24 17:21:02 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: AppMaster received a signal.
15/04/24 17:21:02 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Deleting staging directory .sparkStaging/application_1422443857468_0511
```

Comment: Well.... as you are not using any of the Spark functionality, why do you even need spark here. Now, reading the error message we can derive that your issue has nothing to do with your code but has to do with your HDFS + Spark setup. And we have no information of your HDFS + Spark setup. So... I don't think this questions is answerable at the moment.

Comment: When i run the job i also get this
5/04/24 17:20:46 INFO yarn.Client: Uploading file:/local/spark110/lib/spark-assembly-1.1.0.2.1.5.0-702-hadoop2.4.0.2.1.5.0-695.jar to hdfs://service-10-0.local:8020/user/fredrikb/.sparkStaging/application_1422443857468_0511/spark-assembly-1.1.0.2.1.5.0-702-hadoop2.4.0.2.1.5.0-695.jar

So the file is loaded

Comment: Well... as I said... Spark has to be built for specific versions of Hadoop and even after that you have to make sure that your setup is properly configured. This is a problem with your Hadoop + Spark setup.

Comment: Also... may be it is from a different run attempt... but notice the difference `application_1422443857468_0507` and `application_142244385‌​7468_0511`.

Comment: Did you try the [Spark Notebook](https://github.com/andypetrella/spark-notebook). It comes with built in support for WISP and other charting libs. It will also automagically plot some datasets in table format.

Comment: I have a 30 tb dataset with weather data. Im making solutions to a problem in different languages to compare runtimes etc. The calculations and everything is ok, but I just need to present the result as a chart. The code above is not my solution, but i get the same error.

Comment: Hey! I'm the author of wisp. Have you been able to run a spark application, independently from wisp? Can you paste the entire run-script you used to launch this application?

Comment: I am able to run spark and scala applications without wisp. It also worked when i had imported wisp and included it in the sbt build but not used any of its functions in the code. Im not at the office now so i dont remember the run script, but it was something like : 
/bin/spark-submit  --class HarryPlotter --master yarn-cluster --num-executors 3 --driver-memory 512m --executor-memory 512m --executor-cores 1 myJarBuiltWithSbt.jar

or:  /bin/spark-submit  --class HarryPlotter --master yarn-cluster myJarBuiltWithSbt.jar

Comment: The error you're getting makes me believe wisp was not included in the jar passed to the driver. Have you been able to use other libraries (besides spark) in your application? How did you build `myJarBuiltWithSbt.jar` ? If you used `sbt package` can you try using `sbt assembly` instead? You'll need the assembly plugin, something like this `addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.13.0")`

Comment: Have not tried with other libraries. I used compile then package. Inspecting the resulting jar it seems that it doesn't include the other jars. When i tried with the assembly i got 101 errors like this:

[error] (*:assembly) deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Users/fredrik/.ivy2/cache/com.esotericsoftware.kryo/kryo/bundles/kryo-2.21.jar:com/esotericsoftware/minlog/Log$Logger.class
[error] /Users/fredrik/.ivy2/cache/com.esotericsoftware.minlog/minlog/jars/minlog-1.2.jar:com/esotericsoftware/minlog/Log$Logger.class

Comment: libraryDependencies ++= Seq( "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.1.0" % "provided",
        "com.quantifind" %% "wisp" % "0.0.4")

This worked. Now i have a fat jar with wisp included! Will test it on the cluster on monday!

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked. But how do I save the result as a file?